# Not getting Mnemonic in eclipse while running eclipse plug-in project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have created a Menu named MY Command and I mentioned M as mnemonic but when I press 'alt' I am not getting any underline inside the menu keyword.
I think I am missing something for adding underline below the Menu.
Please suggest me the resolution of this problem.

```
 <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.actionSets">

<!--Menu Action Set-->
<actionSet
            label="Menu Action Set"
            visible="true"
            id="LGProject.actionSet">
            <menu
            label="MY Command"
            id="Menu"
            mnemonic="M"
            >
```

Comment: But if you hit ALT+M, does your menu open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add & before the string/text value